# Left join by merge function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, left-join

I have a two tables want to make a left join

table A

```
ID | Name | Birthday | Salary

1  |  Tom | 01/12/80 | 29382
2  | Kate | 21/2/90  | 39383
3  | Ini  | 23/8/92  | 28287
```

table B

```
ID | Name | Birthday | Home

1  |  Tom | 01/2/80  | Chur
2  | Kate | 21/2/90  | Blu
3  | Ini  | 20/9/92  | La
```

I want to make a left join with the result like

```
ID | Name | Birthday | Salary | Home

1  |  Tom | 01/12/80 | 29382  |  Chur
2  | Kate | 21/2/90  | 39383  |  Blu
3  | Ini  | 23/8/92  | 28287  |  La
```

my code is

```
join_table = tableA.merge(tableB['Home'], how = 'left', on =['ID'])
```

But the result come out like

```
ID | Name | Birthday | Salary | Home

1  |  Tom | 01/12/80 | 29382  |  Chur
1  |  Tom | 01/2/80  | 29382  |  Chur
2  | Kate | 21/2/90  | 39383  |  Blu
3  | Ini  | 23/8/92  | 28287  |  La
3  | Ini  | 20/9/92  | 28287  |  La
```

The ID 1 and 3 are duplicate as they have different birthday data but same ID in both table. 
Any one could help? Thanks

Comment: Did you try `join_table = tableA.merge(tableB, how = 'left', on =['ID'])`? Does it give you the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
join_table = tableA.merge(tableB['Home'], how = 'left', on =['ID']).drop_duplicates(subset=['Name'], keep='first')
```

Comment: There is no "ID" column in tableB as tableB['Home'] is only used in the merge()

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps: Include 'ID' and 'Home' in tableB merge

```
join_table = tableA.merge(tableB[['ID','Home']], how = 'left', on =['ID'])
print(join_table)
```

output:

```
   ID  Name  Birthday  Salary  Home
0   1   Tom  01/12/80   29382  Chur
1   2  Kate   21/2/90   39383   Blu
2   3   Ini   23/8/92   28287    La
```

Comment: the code run without error but still the same result with duplicate.

Comment: Based on your sample input I got the output without duplicates. Try .drop_duplicates()

Answer (score 0):

```
 import pandas as pd
 pd.merge(tableA,tableB,on=['ID','Name','Birthday'],how='left')
```

Comment: this will still give you all the merged columns not in the expected result

Comment: there was minor change

Answer (score 0):

As you don't need the birthday from table B don't use it and merge on Name or ID:

`join_table = tableA.merge(tableB['Home','Name','ID'], how = 'left', on = 'ID')`

Comment: What if table B have more than 10 column, do I have to code like: join_table = tableA.merge(tableB['Home',......, 'Name','ID'], how = 'left', on = 'ID')   ????? @mtpelerin

Comment: I guess. Or take it an other way: drop columns you don"t need. Btw a good work habit is to only use data you need :)
merging can have a high cost. Do your data selection before, on both (or mulitple dataframes) then merge.